# Using MongoDB in C#, how do I derive a TimeSpan from a value in a record?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

This is what I would like to work:

```
var myCollection = collection.Where(r =>
                    r.ChannelId == channelId &&
                    r.Type == ResourceType.RedundancyLock &&
                    r.GroupId == groupId &&
                    (r.OwnerId == "" ||
                     r.OwnerId == ownerId ||
                     r.LastUpdateTime < DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(r.TimeDelta))));
```

Sadly, this results in an exception:

```
    "Unsupported where clause: (r.LastUpdateTime < (Nullable<DateTime>)DateTime:(2014-08-18T20:26:44.6861998Z).Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds((Double)r.TimeDelta)))."
```

The following query works:

```
var myCollection = collection.Where(r =>
                        r.ChannelId == channelId &&
                        r.Type == ResourceType.RedundancyLock &&
                        r.GroupId == groupId &&
                        (r.OwnerId == "" ||
                         r.OwnerId == ownerId ||
                         r.LastUpdateTime < DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))));
```

Is there any way that I can derive a timespan from a value of a record?

Comment: Have you tried assigning the `DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))` to a var and comparing against that? With most query analyzers (including EF) you can't pass in `DateTime` in that way and have to assign it and pass that in.

Comment: @siva.k THe point is I don't know what the value I want to pass into the TimeSpan.FromSeconds() method without knowing what the r.Delta is.  The DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)) works correctly.

Comment: Oops, I see, I was backwards, disregard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to do a 2 stage query.  Filter your there clause for as much as you can.

```
var hold = collection.Where(r =>
                r.ChannelId == channelId &&
                r.Type == ResourceType.RedundancyLock &&
                r.GroupId == groupId);
```

Then pull down the data from the server

```
var holdList = hold.ToList();
```

Then Use your last Query

```
return holdList.Where(r =>   (r.OwnerId == "" ||
         r.OwnerId == ownerId ||
         r.LastUpdateTime < DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(r.TimeDelta))));
```

It is less than optimal because you are pulling more from the database than you need. And also, You're using more memory on the web server than you would otherwise. But the end result should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in a single `MongoDB` query. That would require building the query with values from the document itself which `MongoDB` can't do.

Here is a simpler equivalent query that can't work:

```
{
    "FirstName" : "LastName"
}
```

On this document:

```
{
    "FirstName" : "Bar" 
    "LastName" : "Arnon"
}
```

There are workarounds using JavaScript but they aren't usually efficient.